# Does MySQL still handle indexes in this way?

Tags: mysql, performance, index, myisam

Dropping a duplicate index in MySQL was taking rather long, so while I was waiting I searched about it & found [this post](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/202489) from 2006, talking about how MySQL handles `ADD` and `DROP` index.

> If a table T is a MySQL table having four indexes (ndx1,ndx2,ndx3,ndx4)
>   and you want to 'alter table T drop index ndx3;' here is exactly what
>   happens under the hood:
>
> 1) MySQL copies T.MYD to a temp table, i.e., S.MYD and a zero byte S.MYI.
>   2) MySQL does 'alter table S add index ndx1 (...);
>   3) MySQL does 'alter table S add index ndx2 (...);
>   4) MySQL does 'alter table S add index ndx4 (...);
>   5) MySQL deletes T.MYD and deletes T.MYI
>   6) MySQL renames S.MYD to T.MYD, and renames S.MYI to T.MYI

Is this still true? Is his advice still valid?

> Given the same MyISAM table T having four indexes (ndx1,ndx2,ndx3,ndx4)
>   and you want to 'alter table T drop index ndx3;' try this instead:
>
> 1) create table T1 like T;
>   This creates an empty table T1 with indexes ndx1,ndx2,ndx3 and ndx4.
>   2) alter table T1 drop index ndx3;
>   This drops index ndx3 on the empty T1, which should be instantaneous.
>   3) insert into T1 select * from T;
>   This will populate table T and load all three(3) indexes for T1 in one pass.
>   4) drop table table T;
>   5) alter table T1 rename to T;

How do you all handle adding and removing indexes from large tables?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is how MySQL 4.x did this and it used to severely aggravate me.

In fact, there was a formula I computed on how many such index maneuvers were needed

```
Table with 0 indexes and adding 1 index tooks 1 temp table
Table with 1 index   and adding 1 index tooks 3 temp tables
Table with 2 indexes and adding 1 index tooks 6 temp tables
Table with 3 indexes and adding 1 index tooks 10 temp tables (I had eyewitnessed this !!!)
.
.
.
Table with n indexes and adding 1 index took (n + 1) X (n + 2) / 2 temp tables
.
.
.
Table with 16 indexes and adding 1 index took 153 temp tables
```

**Good News, MySQL 5.x does not do that !!!**

If MySQL 5.x did this, I would be a PostgreSQL DBA today (No offense to PostgreSQL, it is an excellent RDBMS in its own right).

### UPDATE

Oh my goodness, I read the post !!! **That post came from me** !!!

I never thought someone would dig this post up.

Please leave stuff like this dead and buried. Now I am having flashbacks !!!